# Mostrar página segun su logueo

Tags: php, html

Hola buenas tardes tengo una pregunta, ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una página distinta si se logea un vendedor o un administrador, ya sea por meio de su matricula?

```
$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($filas > 0) {
 header ("location: home.php");
} else {
  header("Location: index.php?error=true");
}
```

Comment: Te falta mucho desarrollo en tu pregunta y muestra de lo que tenés. 
Suponiendo que los usuario estan en una base de datos y usas sesiones, tendrás un campo que lo identifique con un nivel de acceso. Al loguearse lo direccionas según el tipo de acceso del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tienes una pantalla de registro de usuarios, de ser así, podrías asignarle un **rol** al momento de registrar un usuario, con este dato podrías validar si es un **vendedor** o un **administrador**, espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

buenas tardes.

No me queda en claro tu código, pero entiendo la premisa "mostrar páginas distintas para distintos usuarios", dicho eso voy a explicarte una forma que es la más usual simplificando algunas cosas.

Para empezar asumo tienes la parte de registro medio realizada con MySQL que es lo clásico, en ese registro usas `session_start()` y `session_id();` para obtener la sesión (es un código de números y letras) de ese usuario (navegador), esa sesión deberías guardarla en alguna tabla relacionándola con el id del usuario que corresponde y si es un vendedor o administrador.

La información sobre las funciones mencionadas puedes obtenerla en [php.net](https://www.php.net/)

Bueno con eso ahora supongamos que tus usuarios entran en "divisor.php" acá es algo parecido a lo que tienes digamos:

```
if($tipo_usuario == "admin") {
    header ("Location: admin.php");
} else {
    header("Location: vendedor.php");
}
```

La variable `$tipo_usuario` la obtendrías usando la sesión que ya tendrías relacionado con un usuario en concreto cuando se registró y al saber el usuario sabes el tipo.

Por último, la parte más importante, los php "admin" y "vendedor" estarían expuestos a todo mundo y yo entiendo es algo que solo podrían ver los usuarios que se registraron, así que en la parte superior de cada php lo primero que se tiene que ejecutar es una validación que compare la sesión del que intenta conectarse con las sesiones que tienes guardadas de los usuarios registrados, si no está, pones un `exit;` con algún mensaje o lo que quieras.

Fue medio simple, pero espero te sirva ;).